# In R, why does a variable with a name beginning with '.' not appear in my environment?

Tags: r

In R when I assign a variable with a name starting with `.` such as `.a <- 3`, it does not appear in my environment in R Studio. However, when I run the variable `.a`, it prints `3` to the console.

Why is the variable `.a` not appearing in my environment but is still able to be accessed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `all.names = TRUE` in `ls`

```
ls(all.names = TRUE)
```

According to `?ls`

> all.names - a logical value. If TRUE, all object names are returned. If FALSE, names which begin with a . are omitted.